# Print output only separated by commas

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

Hi I'm trying to print write on a .csv file on python and I want my output to only be separated by commas. I removed the brackets from print() so that no parenthesis were present but this also cleared out commas. How can I fix this?
This is my code:

```
print self.t, len(self.sAgentList), len(self.iAgentList), len(self.rAgentList)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `csv` module?

Answer (score 1):

The *best* solution is to use a `csv.writer` to write the data.

```
import csv
import sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(['1', '2', '3'])
```

Here I write to `sys.stdout`, but you can write to whatever file-like object that you like.  Note that `writerow` takes a list of strings.  If that isn't what you have, you need to make sure that the inputs are strings... e.g.:

```
writer.writerow([
    str(item) for item in 
    (self.t, len(self.sAgentList), len(self.iAgentList), len(self.rAgentList))])
```

If you want to use `print`, you can supply the `sep` argument (assuming that you are using the print *function* rather than python2.x's print statement):

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(1, 2, 3, sep=',')
```